# How can I erase the datastore if my quota is expired?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a google app deployed and I want to clean up the database (and dump it before cleaning it). The problem is that I overcame my quota for "Datastore Read Operations" .
I strongly believe that I reached the quota when I tried to dump the db via the Datastore admin page. So not by really "using" my app.

Now, when I try to delete all entries from within the app I get an error

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$OverQuotaException: The API call 
datastore_v3.RunQuery() required more quota than is available
```

If I try to browse to Datastore Admin, nothing gets displayed, and on Application settings i got an error.  I have 800k entries, so do it manually is not an option.

I don't want to give up my db, I don't want to pay, I want to set the space free.

Anyone?

Comment: What do you want to do than? You don't want to erase it, you don't want to keep it, what do you want?

Answer (score 2):

Deleting uses quota since it requires updated the datastore indexes.
Dumping the db via the Datastore admin page requires quota since you're using read ops.
In the app engine world, those operations are still considered "using" the datastore.

Pretty much anything you do with the datstore will use read or write ops.

Your options would be either to pay for it, or dump and delete slowly over time so that you use only the number of free ops you have each day.  Write a script using the remote API to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Your database quota gets refilled every day, so you may write a daily cron job with the simple

```
db.delete(YourModel.all(keys_only=True))
```

and leave it running for a few days. hopefully it will delete as much as it could in one day and do the rest in the following days.

besides the cron job, you may do this manually via interactive console or via remote_api or through the Database Admin in your application dashboard menu, where you may select entities and delete them with one button click.